# Use of statistics in this field

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-chemistry, kinetics, atoms

I am currently pursuing a statistics course and I an interested in knowing how can statistics help this field in future. (I am interested because I love chemistry very much) Specifically, are there any open problems in chemistry which have remained as a conjecture or we have not been able to solve due to lack of adequate knowledge of statistics ?

Comment: I am answering because I love statistics very much. Statistics is a terrible battle ground and (as of my experiences) has more pitfalls than answers. It is definitely a most valuable tool in the hands of those who know how to handle it. So here is my advise: a) don't expect too much b) be sure how to handle your tools and, c) above all, gain some experience on how to interpret the results.

Comment: The tags suggest an answer towards physical chemistry, but the use of statistics in factorial design and principal component analysis, as well as the evolution of these as subjects are extremely useful in industrial process optimisation,  from food to organic chemistry to machine settings. Where this could be focused better, for example,  is the excipient mixture composition of tablets and the solid state characteristics arising from each potential mixture with the active ingredient(s).

Comment: @Beerhunter : It would be of more help if you can suggest a link to something of this sort. aren't there any open challenges in chemistry involving mathematics?

Comment: From a commercial angle, the challenges change if companies offer a financial incentive as they set deadlines. For open (academic?)  challenges I can't help, but at the risk of being pilloried for putting links in,  look at www.innocentive.com and ninesigma.com for commercial challenges currently under investigation across all sciences. You may have to check every few weeks to get something relating to what you're talking about.